# '^M' was added to my file after when moving from Win to Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I created a .txt file on Win 8 [using sublime] (with copied text for here) and moved it to my VM running Linux.

I used `cat tmp.txt >> .bashrc` to append those lines into *.bashrc* but mysterious `^M` were added in the end of every line (I noticed after `sourch .bashrc` failed).

I removed those and now it's fine, but where did they come from?

Before and After image:[image]

Comment: Just Google for "^M character in text file" and you'll get the result immediately [What is the ^M character called?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134695/44425), [What does ^M character mean in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5843495/995714), [`^M` in many lines in source code files. How can I remove them?](https://superuser.com/q/395439/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple...

On Windows end-of-line is actually handled with 2 characters: ˆM (Carriage Return) and ˆJ (Line-Feed).
Unix-like systems, like Linux, only use ˆJ.
You save the file on Windows and Linux shows you the ˆM as a normal character.
I never used Sublime, but it probably has an option to convert between the 2 formats so you can just save the file in Unix format from Sublime.
(In fact: most text/programmers-editors have such options.)

Comment: it's not ^N. The newline in Windows is `\r\n` or `0D 0A` which is `^M ^J` because J is the 10th character in the alphabet

Comment: Google(unix2dos, dos2unix)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Oh dear. Good you caught that. I've been doing too much C programming lately.